# Add device name and size to shell selection script

Tags: bash, shell, installation, sh

I am writing a shell script to install Arch Linux, currently, I have a very basic disk selection but it does not give enough information, how can I add extra information such as the disk name and size but keep the `$DISK` variable the same (ie: `/dev/nvme0n1`)

```bash
select_disk () {
    count=0

    for device in `lsblk -d | tail -n+2 | cut -d" " -f1`; do
    count=$((count+1))
    dev[$count]=$device
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$count" "$device"
    done

    read -rp "Select disk (numbers 1-$count): " selection

    DISK="/dev/${dev[$selection]}"
    echo "$DISK" > /tmp/disk
    echo "Installing on $DISK."
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the columns format `lsblk` offers using the `-o` flag. Also, you can avoid the `tail` (which I believe is to remove the header) by using the `lsblk` flag `-n` which does exactly that. Something like this:

```bash
select_disk () {
    count=0
    
    # by default the 'for' loop splits by spaces, change that
    # to split by breaklines by redefining IFS
    IFS=$'\n'

    for device_info in `lsblk -d -n -o NAME,TYPE,SIZE`; do
    count=$((count+1))
    device_name=$(echo $device_info | cut -d" " -f1)
    dev[$count]=$device_name
    printf '%s: %s\n' "$count" "$device_info"
    done

    read -rp "Select disk (numbers 1-$count): " selection

    DISK="/dev/${dev[$selection]}"
    echo "$DISK" > /tmp/disk
    echo "Installing on $DISK."
}
```

Here is only showed the NAME, TYPE and SIZE, but you can add all the columns you want (separated by a comma). See `lsblk -h` (the help) for all possible options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you are calling 'disk name' but...

Let's consider, in your 'for;do..done' loop, that $device is your mapped device name (i.e: sda).

You may get the following information:

1)The device label (if exist):

```
lsblk "/dev/${device}" -dn -o LABEL
```

2)The device vendor:

```
lsblk "/dev/${device}" -dn -o VENDOR
```

3)The device size (in human readable format)

```
lsblk "/dev/${device}" -dn -o SIZE
```

and multiple other informations like:

4)device type:

```
lsblk "/dev/${device}" -dn -o TYPE
```

5)Hardware block sizes

```
lsblk "/dev/${device}" -dn -o PHY-SEC,LOG-SEC
```

6)Linux owners and group assigned to this object

```
lsblk "/dev/${device}" -dn -o OWNER,GROUP
```

Or anything in the below list:

NAME KNAME MAJ:MIN FSTYPE MOUNTPOINT LABEL UUID PARTTYPE PARTLABEL PARTUUID PARTFLAGS RA RO RM HOTPLUG MODEL SERIAL SIZE STATE OWNER GROUP MODE ALIGNMENT MIN-IO OPT-IO PHY-SEC LOG-SEC ROTA SCHED RQ-SIZE TYPE DISC-ALN DISC-GRAN DISC-MAX DISC-ZERO WSAME WWN RAND PKNAME HCTL TRAN SUBSYSTEMS REV VENDOR ZONED

hope it helps.

Comment: It turns out it was the "MODEL" value that gave me the best idea of where I am installing thanks, mate.